# how to add emmeans errorbars to geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar, emmeans

I'm attempting to put error bars on my ggplot geom_bar using `emmeans`, so that my upper/lower bounds for confidence intervals are calculated by the my model predictions. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to manually had these error bars into my barplot and haven't found info online about this yet.

For this post, I'm using the default `pigs` dataset as a toy example to plot source by percentage. Here's my plot:

```
pigs_plot <- pigs %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=source, y=percent, fill=source)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(), stat="summary")
```

Then using emmeans, I calculated the upper and lower confidence levels from the below model:

```
lm1 = lm(log(conc) ~ source + percent, data = pigs)
emm1 = emmeans::emmeans(lm1, specs = "percent", by="source")
```

How do I now insert these values as errors bars for each source type into my barplot? This code was taken from this resource: https://garthtarr.github.io/meatR/emmeans.html

Comment: It probably will help to understand that emm1 is not a data frame. So use as.data.frame(emm1) to get the values to plot.

Comment: The values from `emm1` are marginal means (& their associated confidence intervals) for `log(conc)`, while your plot uses the original `percent` column values on the y-axis. How do you expect to insert the former into the latter? It may help if you include a sketch of your ideal result.

Comment: BTW, you could just do `plot(emm1, type = "response")` and that provides a graph similar to what you seem to want.